# How to get the list of USB type Ethernet adapters connected to my computer using C#?

Tags: c#, usb, ethernet

I am trying to list all the *USB type* Ethernet adapters that are connected to my computer in C#. Kinda like this one (https://www.amazon.de/Logilink-UA0144B-Fast-Ethernet-Adapter/dp/B007D89YS6).

I have managed to list all the Ethernet adapters connected to my computer, including those on the motherboard and those connected via USB adapters. But, how to get only those connected via USB device Ethernet ones?

Comment: even if its connected through USB the OS detected as ethernet card, you cannot distinguich between them

Comment: Perhaps you should consider enumerating USB devices of the CDC device class?